# How to stop execution of piece of code in android until data is retrieved from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to perform some task based on the data retrieved from Firebase.

```
for (inti=0;i<dateList.size();i++)
{
    attendanceDateRef= attendanceRef.child(dateList.get(i));
    attendanceClassRef= attendanceDateRef.child(ViewAttendanceSelectClassActivity.selectedClass);
    attendanceClassRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshotdataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshotdsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                attendanceList.add(dsp.getValue(String.class));
                Log.e("attendanceListValues",dsp.getValue(String.class));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseErrordatabaseError) {

        }
    });
}


intindex=1;

for (inti=1;i<=attendanceList.size();i++)
{
    if(i%4==0)
    {
        fullDateRangeList.add(dateList.get(index));
        index++;
    }
    else
    {
        fullDateRangeList.add(dateList.get(index));
    }

}

Log.e("fullDateRangeList",String.valueOf(fullDateRangeList.size()));
Log.e("attendanceList",String.valueOf(attendanceList.size()));
```

above code is written on the `OnClick` event of a `Button` , when I click on the `Button` following output is generated on `logcat`:

```
fullDateRangeList:0
attendanceList:0
attendanceListValues:Value1
attendanceListValues:Value2
attendanceListValues:Value3
attendanceListValues:Value4
.
.
.
attendanceListValues:ValueN
```

from the above output it looks like second loop is executing before data is retrieved from Firebase and that is why size of fullDateRange and attendanceList is 0.

is there any way i can prevent second loop from executing until data is stored in attendanceList?

Comment: put executeable code in listener that will be executed after listener called

Comment: above code is written on the OnClickListener of button

Comment: addValueEventListener is asynchronous.  It doesn't block, and you shouldn't try to make it block.  You have to response to data in the callback.  This will require a big restructuring of your code.

Comment: `onDataChange` is other listener

Comment: a very simple solution, add everything that is gonna use the data retrieved inside `ondatachange` and add a `return` after the else, then your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop that method or make it wait until you get the all the data from your database. This is the behaviour of an asynchronous method. You need to change the logic of your code a little bit by declaring and using that data only inside the `onDataChange()` method, otherwise it will be always empty.

Also there is another approach. If you want, you can dive into the asynchronous world and use my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).